# ViewPager with ListView inside fragment - listview isn't updating when modified

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-viewpager

When I add or remove an item from the listview, the listview isn't updated unless I scroll offscreen in the viewpager and then back, triggering the OnCreate method again in the fragment.  This is based on the viewpager template in eclipse - I just added a listview to the fragment instead of just a textview.  Putting notifyDataSetChanged doesn't help nor did adding an OnResume to the fragment.  Below is the mainactivity.  The adapter and listview have the correct items in them, but they are not being displayed until you scroll at least two pages over (offscreen on my device, may be more or less on others) and then back. What am I missing?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
static ArrayAdapter adapter;
private static DataElementTable dataElementTable;
private static ItemTable ItemTable;
private static int currentTab = 0;
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
    // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
    // a reference to the Tab.
    mViewPager
            .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
            });

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
        // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
        // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
        // this tab is selected.
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

        dataElementTable = new DataElementTable(this);
        dataElementTable.open(); 

        itemTable = new ItemTable(this);
        itemTable.open();
     }

@Override
protected void onResume() {
  dataElementTable.open();
  itemTable.open();
  super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
  dataElementTable.close();
  itemTable.close();
  super.onPause();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        addNewItem();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
    // the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

   private void addNewItem()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        alert.setTitle("New Item");
        alert.setMessage("Enter New Item Name:");

        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        alert.setView(input);

        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
          String value = input.getText().toString();

          Log.d("pos", "newitem " + currentTab);
          Item newItem = itemTable.createItem(currentTab - 1, value);

          }
        });

        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            // Canceled.
          }
        });

        alert.show();
    }

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below).
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 7 total pages.
        return 7;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
        case 2:
            return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        case 3:
            return getString(R.string.title_section4).toUpperCase(l);
        case 4:
            return getString(R.string.title_section5).toUpperCase(l);
        case 5:
            return getString(R.string.title_section6).toUpperCase(l);
        case 6:
            return getString(R.string.title_sectionX).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
     ListView listView;

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber)
    {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
                ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
          currentTab = (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)) - 1;

          listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview);
           ArrayList<String> listItems1 = new ArrayList<String>();
           ArrayList<String> listItems2 = new ArrayList<String>();
           ArrayList<String> listItems3 = new ArrayList<String>();
           ArrayList<String> listItems4 = new ArrayList<String>();
           ArrayList<String> listItems5 = new ArrayList<String>();
           ArrayList<String> listItems6 = new ArrayList<String>();    
           ArrayList<String> listItemsLog = new ArrayList<String>();



           listItems1 = itemTable.getAllItemsForCategory(0);
        listItems2 = itemTable.getAllItemsForCategory(1);
            listItems3 = itemTable.getAllItemsForCategory(2);
        listItems4 = itemTable.getAllItemsForCategory(3);
        listItems5 = itemTable.getAllItemsForCategory(4);
        listItems6 = itemTable.getAllItemsForCategory(5);


          Log.d("pos", "createview " + currentTab);
            switch (currentTab)
            {
            case 0:
            {
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, listItems1);
            }
            break;
            case 1:
            {
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, listItems2);
            }
            break;
            case 2:
            {
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, listItems3);
            }
            break;
            case 3:
            {
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, listItems4);
            }
            break;
            case 4:
            {
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, listItems5);
            }
            break;
            case 5:
            {
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, listItems6);
            }
            break;
            case 6:
            {
                listItemsLog = dataElementTable.getAllElements();
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, listItemsLog);
            }
            break;
            default:
            {
                assert(false);
            }
            break;
            }

            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();     

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `notifyDataSetChanged` in the `onCreateView` method.  `onCreateView` is called when you are scrolling through your `ListView`, and then data is updating on your screen.  You need to call `notifyDataSetChanged` immediately after you change data in your adapter, not in `onCreateView`.